# Xcode IOS-No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I tried to distribute my app to the app store but it failed with an error.

No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.

More information: - Xcode Version 13.0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAxva.png)

Comment: how did you solved the issue? as i am having the same issue with xcode 13.1

Comment: have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

iOS bundle Executable string was changed with the project name in my Flutter project. I dont know why so I solved this issue like this

ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist

```
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>TestAppName</string>
```

to

```
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>App</string>
```